# How do I select a value of a dropdown in MVC by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m using this dropdownlist in my cshtml page. Its consits of

```
new SelectListItem
     {
        Value = x.TitleID.ToString(),
        Text = x.TitleDescription
     });

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserLoginModels.TitleID, Model.UserLoginModels.Title, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "title" })
```

I need to select a value by using javascript

I tried on this way.

```
var dlTitle = $("#userCreate #title").data("kendoDropDownList");
$("#title").Value(3);
```

But it gives "dlTitle  is undefined"

Comment: directly try `$('#title').val(3);`

Comment: Directly Try `var dlTitle = $("#title").data("kendoDropDownList")`

Comment: Your dropdown seems like a normal mvc dropdown not a kendo. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id` is unique, you just need to use:

```
var dlTitle = $("#title").data("kendoDropDownList")
```

As well as checking whether you're using `dlTitle` before you've defined it since you got that error from console log.

Answer (score 0):

#### A few things to note.

**1.** You should stay away from descendant selectors where the ID is the last descendant. An ID should be unique and only applied to a single DOM element per page. In your case you are using 2 ID's `$("#userCreate #title")` to try and access the DOM element with the ID of `#title`. With that said, it should look like the following:

```
var dlTitle = $("#title").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

**2.** If you are trying to interact with a [Kendo UI DropDownList](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/dropdownlist/overview#accessing-an-existing-dropdownlist), then accessing an instance of the DropDownList would be done by the above code via the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) as you have stated in your example `var dlTitle = $("#title").data("kendoDropDownList");`. This will give you a reference to that instance.

To retrieve the value of the currently selected option you would need to place the following after your Kendo DropDownList for ASP.NET MVC declaration:

```
@* razor view logic for your DropDownList goes here *@

<script type="javascript">
$(function() {
    // Retrieve an instance of the DropDownList
    var dlTitle = $("#title").data("kendoDropDownList");

    // Log the output of the currently selected value of the DropDownList
    console.log(dlTitle.val());
});
</script>
```

It is very important that this script block is placed after the ASP.NET MVC declaration. If not you'll run into a scenario where your script is being called before the DropDownList has has a chance to instantiate.

**3.** If your intention is to set the value of the DropDownList, then you would do the following:

```
@* razor view logic for your DropDownList goes here *@

<script type="javascript">
$(function() {
    // Retrieve an instance of the DropDownList
    var dlTitle = $("#title").data("kendoDropDownList");

    // Set the value of the DropDownList to the
    // 4th option in the list
    dlTitle.val(3);

    // Set the value of the DropDownList to the option
    // in the list that has a value of `foobar`
    dlTitle.val('foobar');
});
</script>
```

Please note that the same applies here as it does in Point #2, where you will need to make sure that script block is placed after the ASP.NET MVC declaration.